# Is a "back to previous page" link redundant?

Tags: html, back

I am asking this question from the stand point of a web developer. I found out from this site that a "reset" button on a form page is mostly redundant. I would like to know whether it is the same for a "go back to previous page" link since all browsers have a back button.

```
<a href='previous-page'>Back</a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Context is missing, with question do you refer to with ' from this site that '...?

Comment: Not unless you need to perform special programmed action when you hit `Back`.

Comment: @home: stackoverflow site, I mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a thing is rarely seen except on old sites where you navigate through a series of forms. The link on the page would avoid form resubmission. Usually there would also be some explanation of why you are supposed to click the link instead of the built-in button.

Current best practices obviate the need and it would now be an anachronism.

Some sites have static links labeled "back" and leading to the homepage or other index page. That's just a case of mislabeling, or extreme shortsightedness.

Comment: Good points. Something like booking an air ticket?

Comment: @BenHuh Yeah, I'm pretty sure I remember one on my annual ethics quizzes too. But as I mentioned, modern websites should use post/redirect/get or other means of coordinating forms that work with the button.

Answer (score 1):

It may or may not be redundant, depends on the page. It's possible that your site is organized in a way you do a couple redirects; so back button will work not as most users expect. I don't say it's a good practice, but I saw quite a few sites doing such things.

Comment: I see... Means it is quite redundant if I am not doing any redirects for form submission.

Comment: Redirects shouldn't affect the history. A redirect that breaks the back button is a bug.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It doesn't really 'break' back button. But as an end user I would expect 'back' button to bring me back to the page I was before hitting, for instance, "login" button, not to any of couple pages I was redirected before I finally saw requested page. I.e. "Login"->page 1->page 2->some servlet -> finally landing page. (Page 1,2,  servlet , all these redirections controlled by the server after I hit 'login' and before it finally shows me the page I need)

Comment: @a1ex07 Not sure what you're saying. Whether a redirect is initiated from server-side HTTP or client-side JS or some of both, it can easily be crafted not to affect the back button or history.

Answer (score 0):

If your page is in a wizard like. Most of the time, you'll see a back link, in such case some action can be executed before viewing the previous page.